# Phase portrait of piece-wise ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find $x(t)$ for the piece-wise equation to sketch its phase portrait:

$$x'=-x \quad \text{for}\quad  |x|\le 1$$ 
$$x'=-2x \quad \text{for}\quad |x|>1$$

By inspection I can tell that the answers are $k_1 e^{-t}$ and $k_2 e^{-2*t}$.

However I'm not sure if I have to get also new intervals in time for $x(t)$ and which would those be (it came to my mind as there are no way to get $x=-1$ with $k_1 e^{-t}$, for example... then I hesitate if I should plot the phase portrait of the system using all the values of x or only the positive ones).

I hope I'm getting clear, thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I reformatted the equations. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: "I need to find x(t) for the piece-wise equation to sketch its phase portrait" No, actually the whole idea is that it is much simpler to draw a complete phase portrait than to find solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it came to my mind as there  are no way to get $x=-1$ with $k_1 e^{-t}$

Send that thought back where it came from. The constant  $k_1$ can be negative, in which case $x(t)$ will pass the value $-1$ at some point.

Both parts of the differential equation  prescribe that $|x|$ is a decreasing function of $t$, since the derivative of $x$ has the sign opposite to $x$. Also, every solution grows exponentially if traced backward in time. Therefore, there is a moment $t_0$ when $|x(t_0)|=1$. It follows that 
$$
x(t) = \begin{cases}
e^{2(t_0-t)}x(t_0),\quad t\le t_0  \\  
e^{t_0-t}x(t_0),\quad t\ge t_0 
\end{cases}
$$

But you should not need the solution to draw the phase portrait. Use the entire number line, $-\infty$ to $\infty$. All arrows point toward the origin; they change their magnitude at $\pm 1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks very much for your answer. I would like to have my +15 valoration to upvote you but I hope my greetings will be enough this time. Best regards.